# Multiple receive activities with the same operation name and signature

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have two Receive activities that both have the same operation name and signature (parameters).  Is there a way to correlate a request to the workflow service to a specific Receive activity within a workflow instance?  I understand how to correlate between workflow instances but not sure how (if you even can) to correlate a message to a specific Receive activity.  I have a parameter in the signature of the Receive activity that could be used for the correlation.

Comment: Does the question not make sense? If there's any additional information I could provide that would help please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

See [WF4 Workflow Services–Can you use the Same Operation more than once?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/03/09/wf4-workflow-services-can-you-use-the-same-operation-more-than-once.aspx) for a look at this issue.  Also Rory Primrose did an excellent followup with a technique that might work for you [Calling a workflow service operation multiple times](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2011/03/10/Calling-a-workflow-service-operation-multiple-times.aspx)